# Programmatically navigate with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an web application with ReactTS. I use `react-router` library for navigation and I need to navigate user to registration page on `Registration` button click programmatically.

I found several ways to do that programmatically in `react-router`:

1. with `useNavigate` hook - it can be used only inside components.
2. with `redirect` function - it's work only for loaders.

I use function components with hooks, but do not want to keep a lot of logic inside component. I want to move that logic to services layer. Now I'm searching for way to navigate programmatically without hooks.

That's my code:

```
import { redirect, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AUTHORIZATION_REGISTRATION_MAILBOX } from '../../../constants/routes';

export const LogInComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const goToRegistration = () => {
    redirect(AUTHORIZATION_REGISTRATION_MAILBOX); // it's not working
    navigate(AUTHORIZATION_REGISTRATION_MAILBOX); // it's working but only inside component
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button className='enter-button' onClick={goToRegistration}>
        Registration
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**UPD 1**

I'm looking for solution like that:

1. Component uses service

```
import { registrateUser } from './registrationService'

export const RegistrationComponent = () => {
  
  const registrate = () => {
    registrateUser();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={registrate}>
        Registrate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Service makes some logic and redirect user by navigation service

```
import { redirectTo } from './navigationService'

export const registrateUser = () => {
  
  // makes some logic

  redirectTo(/*some path*/);
}
```

3. Navigation service should redirect user

```
export const registrateUser = (path: string) => {
  window.location.href = path; // as example
}
```

That solution with `window.location.href` is working, but it clears state values (context values and store values). So it's not good decision.

Comment: The version using the `useNavigate` hook and `navigate` function is the correct one of the options you've presented. `useHistory` was a RRDv5 hook, replaced by `useNavigate`, and `redirect` is a RRDv6 loader/action-only utility function. Can you [edit] to explain in greater detail how you are wanting/trying to navigate from outside a React component or custom React hook? See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote " I'm searching for way to navigate programmatically without hooks". Not a hook. I explained the desired solution.

Comment: `window.location.href = path` is effectively a page reload. Use the `useNavigate` hook if you want to effect an imperative navigation action, or render a `Navigate` component if you want to effect a declarative navigation action. Keep in mind that if you are trying to do this logic in a `registrate` callback that `Navigate` won't work in the callback. If you are trying to do something else then it's not clear and you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version using the `useNavigate` hook and navigate function is the correct one of the options you've presented.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AUTHORIZATION_REGISTRATION_MAILBOX } from '../../../constants/routes';

export const LogInComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const goToRegistration = () => {
    navigate(AUTHORIZATION_REGISTRATION_MAILBOX);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button className='enter-button' onClick={goToRegistration}>
        Registration
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you are trying to extract this logic into a reusable unit then you'll likely need to create a custom hook such that the `useNavigate` hook is validly called. Custom React hooks are what allow for code reuse.

Example:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AUTHORIZATION_REGISTRATION_MAILBOX } from '../../../constants/routes';

export const useRegistrateUser = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (/* args? */) => {
    ... other business logic ...

    navigate(AUTHORIZATION_REGISTRATION_MAILBOX);
  };
};
```

```
import { useRegistrateUser } from './registrationService'

export const RegistrationComponent = () => {
  const { registrateUser } = useRegistrateUser();

  const registrate = () => {
    registrateUser(); // <-- pass any args, if necessary
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={registrate}>
        Registrate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well, it seems good, but it is still hook. Can I test it without component? I mean unit tests.

Comment: @АлександрПлеханов Yes, React hooks are testable in isolation: https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/

Comment: @AlexanderPlekhanov FWIW React hooks are the future of React, they aren't going away any time soon.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to test it before answer you) First need to say that that lib does not support React 18v, 17v only. Second - it works strange for me. But if it is solution I will mark your answer

Comment: @AlexanderPlekhanov What are you saying doesn't support React18? What is working strangely for you? Can you clarify?

Comment: 1. react-hooks-testing-library is incompatible with Rect18 (React17 only)

Comment: React18 is supported: https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library#a-note-about-react-18-support It looks like they just incorporated the functionality into the core module.

Comment: I mean:
1. **react-hooks-testing-library** is incompatible with Rect18 (React17 only)
2. Well, to use useNavigation we still need to wrap our hook into BrowserRouter->Routes->Route (with hook wrapper)
3. We need to set `path='*'` to our Route to have `HookRenderResult`.
4. But it works!

Comment: To be honest, I was looking for a simpler solution without the all wrappers and versioning issues, but looks like it's the best one can found. As an alternative, use something like a mobx-router library, but there is a transfer of history through forwarding props. So at least the props will not stick out everywhere. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderPlekhanov Yeah, sorry, I meant that it seems they just integrated the hook testing utilities into the core `@testing-library/react` library, which, AFAIK, are React18 compatible. It *has* been a while since I needed to write unit tests for hooks specifically as it's preferred to unit test them as part of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `useNavigate` hook inside the shared service function, it works for me. Kindly try the below example.

### App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { navigateTo } from "./sharedService";

const App = () => {
    navigateTo('/path');
    return (
        <></>
    );
};

export default App;
```

### SharedService.ts

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const navigateTo = (redirectTo: string) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate(redirectTo);
};
```

Comment: Well, thank you. It's not work for me. I had added that and React throws an run time exception: **Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component**. [Decoder link](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321)

Answer (score 0):

beacause react-router's ability is available in a Provider(Router), so you can only navigate in react-router with compoent.

you can still change `window.location.pathname` directly, but it will let browser reload, so it can't keep app state anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
const LoginPage = (props: LoginPageProps) => {
    const location = useLocation();

    return <Navigate to={'your path'} state={{ from: location }} replace />
}
```